# Unable to Make PostGIS 2.0 - file not found

Tags: postgis, postgresql, postgis-2.0

I am struggling to get the latest trunk of PostGIS to install on a fresh Mac running Lion.  I did install PostGIS 1.5.3-2 for Postgres 9.1 from [KyngChaos Mac OSX Installers][1].  This setup worked fine for me and I was able to setup spatial databases against a PostGreSQL 9.1 database instance.  But I realized I need the new GeoJSON support in the PostGIS 2.0 trunk.  I went ahead and downloaded the latest source code(revision 8401) and compiled with the JSON optional argument (downloaded JSON-C libraries):

```
sudo ./configure --with-gui --with-raster --with-jsondir=/usr/local/
```

The compile works successfully.  My issue is when issuing the make command.  It appears that the make command is looking for a **/usr/bin/postgres/** directory on my system ***which does not exist***:

```
ld: file not found: **/usr/bin/postgres**
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
ld: file not found: /usr/bin/postgres
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
lipo: can't open input file: /var/tmp//cc82cOrG.out (No such file or    directory)
make[1]: *** [postgis-2.0.so] Error 1
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am thus unable to install PostGIS 2.0 on my system.  ***Anyone have any ideas what specific files (libraries, etc) the PostGIS 2.0 install is looking for under /usr/bin/postgres?***

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

During the PostGIS installation the path to pgconfig is needed. Try using the switch "--with-pgconfig" and give the path to your pgconfig-file. If I remember correctly, it is usually in /user/bin but make sure that it is in there.